# Android 5.0 Wrong crop regions on preview surface and captured still image

Tags: android, android-camera, zooming, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to get digital zoomed frame on Android 5.0 with camera2 interface.
Appropriate doc for that functionality is [developer.android.com/camera2/captureRequest](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html#SCALER_CROP_REGION)

Surface used in my application:

- SurafaceView (1920x1080, 16:9 aspect ratio)
- ImageReader (3264x2448, 4:3 aspect ratio)

Camera's sensor size is 3280x2464 (4:3 aspect ratio)

Crop region which I want to get from sensor is:

```
Rect zoomCropPreview = new Rect(1094, 822, 2186, 1642); //(1092x820, 4:3 aspect ratio)
```

I set this Rect as parameter for preview request:

```
previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION, zoomCropPreview);
captureSession.setRepeatingRequest(previewRequestBuilder.build(), null, null);
```

And to take still image:

```
stillRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION, zoomCropPreview);

captureSession.capture(stillRequestBuilder.build(), new captureListener() , null);
```

Expected results:

- Coz crop rectangle is 4:3 ratio, then preview should be cropped vertically (letterbox)
- Still image should be exact crop region.
- Both preview and still image should be centered on the same point of scene, and should differ only in vertical edges.

Real result:

- Preview and still image point on different scene which seems to be moved vertically. Look at attach images.
  [image: Preview surface]

[image: Captured still image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the hardware level of the device ( https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL ) ? If LEGACY, you may be running into an OS bug fixed in later Android releases.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed!
General idea is to calculate crop region for preview and still images separately.

1) Calculate crop region for still image as in initial post (use 4:3 rectangle)

2) For preview take above crop region (4:3) and reduce vertical size to get 16:9 rectangle.

Comment: please explain in detail. I facing same issue. SurafaceView (1024x608, 1.68 aspect ratio)
ImageReader (1024x608, 1.68 aspect ratio)
Camera's sensor size is 4096*2432 (1.68 aspect ratio)