# Android Camera 2, how to crop preview size

Tags: android, preview, android-camera2

I'm working on Camera 2 API recently and my device has a 16:9 screen ratio but my camera sensor is 4:3. So all the preview size I got is 4:3. I' wondering is there any way I get a crop the size and only display the 16:9 part?  I tried a long time and didn't find any help for camera 2.

My current camera code is similar to the [camera 2 basic sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic).

So how should I crop the preview and only display the 16:9 part on the texture view?

Thanks!!

Comment: Answer to this question is provided in the link [Android 5.0 Wrong crop regions on preview surface and captured still image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583489/android-5-0-wrong-crop-regions-on-preview-surface-and-captured-still-image)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `SurfaceTexture` with your ratio 4:3 instead of 16:9.

You could use the custom view from that sample project or create your own with the new `ConstraintLayout` and setting the ratio of height from 16:9 of your width (or inverse).

Then when you set the size of your texture:

```
texture.setDefaultBufferSize(width, height)
```

You will get  not problems streching, because your texture is the same ratio as your camera output.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I [answered a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52051577/3268060) after having this same problem, and not being able to change the aspect ratio of the actual view to match the camera output (as Sulfkain's answer suggests).

Tl;dr: the answer lies in the `configureTransform` in [Camera2BasicFragment](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java).  Although their function is mostly implemented for orientation, the scaling matrix can resolve scaling/aspect ratio issues with views that are the wrong shape for the camera output.

Comment: Seems the sample was re-written at some point. I see configureTransform in the linked code, but not in the latest. ... Thing is, you hint that "the answer lies in configureTransform" ... but what is the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do some debug on 
`setUpCameraOutputs(int width, int height)`
 and check the part that you are selecting the size of the output

```
// Danger, W.R.! Attempting to use too large a preview size could  exceed the camera
// bus' bandwidth limitation, resulting in gorgeous previews but the storage of
// garbage capture data.
mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class), rotatedPreviewWidth, 
rotatedPreviewHeight, maxPreviewWidth, maxPreviewHeight, largest);
```

maybe you have to hard select something there.