# Android Camera2 output resolution does not match requested resolution

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am attempting to capture still images via the Camera2 API. When I request an image resolution via an Image Reader e.g.

```
imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(1920, 1440, ImageFormat.JPEG, 2)
```

I am returned a 1024x768 image. This is despite the fact that 1920x1440 is actually listed in the supported output sizes and 1024x768 isn't!

```
val staticImageSizes: Array<Size> = it.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG)
```

If I request a 1024x768 image I am returned a 1024x576 image! It must support 1024x768 as it previously returned an image in that resolution, and why hasn't it even returned an image in the correct aspect ratio? The output resolution is seemingly random and does not correspond to the "supported" output sizes. It works correctly at lower resolutions i.e. 320x240, 640x480. I basically want to be able to specify a resolution from the the supported outputs that has a 3:4 aspect ratio and actually get an image back that matches that.

Thanks

Comment: Hopefully, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36194159/192373) will help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So the supported output format contains 1920x1080 and the active array size is Rect(0, 0 - 3264, 2448). To me that suggests that if I request an image of size 1920x1080 then it should be capable of returning it in that resolution, however it returns and image 1024x576, which is a different aspect ratio and is also not contained in the support sizes.

Comment: Maybe, you are unlucky to come across some buggy implementation. Which device is this?